# Remove herokuapp sub domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I`m developing some apps and hosting them on heroku

there is a problem which is indexing the website

if i publish it with top level domain there will be conflict between the heroku sub domain and the main one, search engines will index both

for example if my domain is

```
 something.com
```

and heroku sub domain is

```
something.herokuapp.com
```

what should i do to delete heroku sub domain and make it only visible on main one?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible right now. Heroku proposes to implement 301 redirect in such case. Because you don't have access to configuration of web server or some proxy on Heroku side, the only option is to implement it in the application code.

This information is specified [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains):

> Your app’s Heroku Domain will always remain active, even if you’ve set up a custom domain. If you want users to use the custom domain exclusively, your app should send HTTP status 301 Moved Permanently to tell web browsers to use the custom domain. The Host HTTP request header field will show which domain the user is trying to access; send a redirect if that field is example.herokuapp.com.

Comment: You can check out this middleware https://github.com/gbuesing/rack-host-redirect There is an example for your case

Comment: How this is not a default, or at least a simple toggle / flag to turn on, I don't understand. The moment you connect a custom domain, the herokuapp domain serves no purpose other than exposing you to security risks and breaking your application logic.

Comment: @mzrnsh I agree there should be a toggle, but heroku domain can be useful in some unexpected cases. During massive DNS outage we gave our customers an alternative url with heroku domain and it saved the day ;)